# 301 Redirect Issues in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been digging through the archives and threads and can't seem to find anything that matches my 301 Redirect issue -

I am trying to redirect old links to a new site and a problem with the following:

This one works - `Redirect 301 /food-service/ http://www.xxxx.com/food-services.html`

This one does not - `Redirect 301 /food-service/distribution http://www.xxxx.com/distribution.html`

The one that does not work tries to redirect to - `http://www.xxxx.com/food-services.htmldistribution/`

Would you mind lending me your thoughts on what I can do?

Thank you all!

Comment: You should swap them around - though I'm not sure if that will help. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `Redirect` says:

> Then any request beginning with URL-Path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-Path will be appended to the target URL.

The behaviour that you do observe is as we would expect from the documentation. It goes through the `Redirect` directives, and chooses the first one that matches.

To get the correct behaviour, you have to list the most specific redirect first, and the least specific last.

If you would have rules for `/a/b/c`, `/a/b` and `/a`, then you list them in that order.